# Dynamic height Container based on Child Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to achieve dynamic container height based on child Text widget. Text String received from server and dynamic. So whenever I fetch it that should seen properly inside Container. 
I have used following code:

```
Container(
  width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.93,
  height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.20,
  child: Text(strTips, style: TextStyles.knowYourImpact, ),
 )
```

For reference I am adding image.
[image]

Comment: could you please add more detail, however you don't need to define width and height for ``container``, it will take automatic.

Comment: You can use `constraints`, set `minHeight` and `maxHeight` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget:

According to the docs:

> A widget that controls how a child of a `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex` flexes.
>
> Using a `Flexible` widget gives a child of a `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex` the flexibility to expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a `Row` or vertically for a `Column`),

```
Container(
    child: Row(
         children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
                child: Text(strTips, style: TextStyles.knowYourImpact, ))
             ],
         ));
```